# Lightning datatable double click to start inline editing

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is it possible to double click the lightning datatable cell to start inline editing, instead of clicking the pencil icon?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot at least as of today. From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation) -- [*Clicking the icon or pressing the Enter key triggers inline editing*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rolling up the answer from comment to provide more details.

As of today [lightning:datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation) does not allow start inline editing on "double click" of the cell. It only supports inline editing by:

- Clicking the pencil icon that appears for an inline editable cell
- By pressing enter on the cell

Below is the excerpt from documentation:

> Working with Inline Editing
>
> When you make a column editable, a pencil icon appears when you hover over the cells in that column. **Clicking the icon** or **pressing the Enter** key triggers inline editing.